# Angular 7 different menus for different pages

Tags: angular7

The app-component is configured this way,
I want to make an admin page and how to place a different app-navbar

```
 <app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

This is my rooting module.

what changes should I make here

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Home', component:NavComponent,children:[{path:'',component:HomeComponent}] },
  { path: 'Teams', component:TeamsComponent,outlet:'sub' },
  { path: 'Calendar', component:CalendarComponent },
  { path: 'Fixture', component:FixtureComponent },
  { path: 'Gallery', component:GalleryComponent },
  { path: 'Partners', component:PartnersComponent },
  { path: 'Streams', component:StreamsComponent },
  { path: 'Videos', component:VideoComponent },
  {path:'Login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'Ctrl',component:AdminComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

   constructor(){

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define a layout based on your routing

FooterOnlyLayoutComponent:

```
<div class="content" fxFlex>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

To use this layout for the login route, the route has to be specified like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'login',
   component: FooterOnlyLayoutComponent,
   children: [
     { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
   ]
 }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { }
```

Other Layout :

MainLayoutComponent:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'dashboard',
   component: MainLayoutComponent,
   children: [
     { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
   ]
 }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Do I need to create a new module? app-routing.module.ts is useless?

Comment: Can you view the module again?

Comment: No, you can just define all your route in a single array and give the `component` as the base layout for your `children`

Comment: { path: 'Home', component:NavComponent,   children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  ] },

is it?


 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

Comment: Yes, Your code now will warp a `HomeComponent`  inside `NavComponent`. don't forget to add  your HTML in  `NavComponent`  and put  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: HomeCompent did not come

Comment: when you go to #/Home didn's come?

Comment: There are children components inside the house

Comment: +homecomponent
  -slidercomponent
  -our-teamscomponent
  -newscomponent
   -streamcomponent

Comment: `<app-nav> </app-nav>
<app-slider></app-slider>
<app-stream-videos></app-stream-videos>
<app-news></app-news>
<app-our-teams></app-our-teams>
<app-instagram></app-instagram>
`